# Creating rule by AppleScript can't make condition "does not contain"

Tags: automation, applescript

**What is wrong here?!**

```
tell application "Mail"
set newRule to make new rule at end of rules with properties {name:"OutOFoffice", reply text:"I am out of office"}
tell newRule
    make new rule condition at end of rule conditions with properties {rule type:message content, qualifier:does not contain value, expression:"I am out of office"}
end tell
```

end tell

here is the result I got
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o46CZ.png)
I am able to do the opposite but this is what I want

Comment: What's the issue? Does it not compile, or not work at runtime?

Comment: @matt not working at runtime

Comment: What happens at runtime?

Comment: @matt please check the question again, I added a screenshot for my code and the result as well

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes—for no clear reason and with no means to predict ahead of time<sup>**1**</sup> those for which this is true—some properties of an element being newly created (by way of the **`make`** command) can be set at the point of creation, i.e. assigned through the `with properties` parameter, ***but*** some cannot.

A similarly frustrating situation is exemplified with *Finder* where

```
tell application id "com.apple.Finder" to make ¬
         Finder window with properties {target:¬
         disk "data", bounds:{0, 0, 1440, 800}}
```

will make you a new `Finder window` pointed at somewhere that isn't where you want, positioned and sized however it feels.  Both the `target` and `bounds` property have to set **after** creation<sup>**2**</sup>.

There's no *good* reason why this should be the case, a conclusion one can arrive at for much of AppleScript's "feature set".

Anyway, hopefully you'll have foreshadowed that the solution to your problem is to set the property in question after creation.  Here's a one-liner just because:

```
tell application id "com.apple.mail" to tell (make new rule with properties ¬
        {name:"Out of Office", reply text:"I am out of the office"}) to set ¬
        qualifier of (make new rule condition with properties {rule type:¬
        message content, expression:reply text}) to does not contain value
```

---

**¹**<sub>This is AppleScript's tagline.</sub>
**²**<sub>*Finder*'s **`make`** command has a `to` parameter that allows the target to be set **at** creation.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

As CJK points out: You have to set the `qualifier` *after* the creation of the rule. See my script for example:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later

set theProperties to {}

tell application id "com.apple.mail" -- Mail.app
    set theMessages to the selection
    repeat with i in theMessages
        set the end of theProperties to sender of i
    end repeat
    tell rule "SPAM DELETE"
        repeat with i in theProperties
            set qualifier of (make rule condition at end of rule conditions with properties {rule type:from header, expression:i}) to does not contain value
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

This line the solution:

```
set qualifier of (make rule condition at end of rule conditions with properties {rule type:from header, expression:i}) to does not contain value
```